# Which standard deviation of the cross-validation score?

Tags: machine-learning, standard-error, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn

When doing cross-validation for model selection, I found there are many ways to quote the "standard deviation" for the cross-validation scores (here "score" means an evaluation metric e.g. accuracy, AUC, loss, etc.)

1. One way is to calculate the standard deviation on the mean of the scores of $K$ folds (= standard deviation of $K$ folds / $\sqrt K $).
2. The second way is to calculate just the standard deviation of the scores of $K$ folds. An example can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_anova.html).
3. [Another way](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_diabetes.html) which I don't quite understand. It seems to calculate the standard deviation of $K$ folds / $\sqrt N$ where $N$ is the size of the dataset...

Personally I think 1) is correct, as we care more about the standard error on the sample mean (here sample mean = the average score of $K$ folds validation) rather than the standard deviation of the sample. Can anyone explain which way is preferred?

Comment: Directly relevant: http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/grandvalet04a/grandvalet04a.pdf

Comment: As far as I can see, all two examples uses numpy.std of the result of cross_validation.cross_val_score and this returns the "Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation." (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html). So all are really performing the computations you describe in 1).

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 did you find some validation anywhere about one of the three methodologies? thanks

Comment: Not sure if it works as a solution, but I found the following lecture which seems to confirm your point 1 assumption: https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/18-val1.pdf